# Deploying Rails app with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, mediatemple

I just acquired a Media Temple (dv) 4.0 server to deploy a Rails app I created via a git repository.  I'm new to Rails but Capistrano deployment seemed pretty straightforward.  Nonetheless, I've been working all day on getting my first Rails project deployed.  Here's the error I'm getting when I execute "cap production deploy -v" after setup and check:

```
** [out :: 64.207.184.51] rake aborted!
** [out :: 64.207.184.51] no such file to load -- rubygems
```

I have been installing gems all day on the server, so I don't think rubygems isn't installed.  This is after hours of debugging why it was telling me my public key is invalid.

Here are my configuration files:

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'
set :application, 'snippet'
set :domain, '[server IP address]'
set :user, 'root'
```

config/deploy.rb

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :stages, ["production"]
set :default_stage, "production"
set :application, "[app name]"
set :scm, :git
set :repository, "git@github.com:[github.com repository]"
set :branch, "master"
set :user, "root"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm_passphrase, "[public ssh key passphrase]"
```

config/deploy/production.rb

```
server "[server IP]", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs"
```

output of error:

```
vespertine:snippet nporteschaikin$ cap production deploy -v
** transaction: start
/Users/nporteschaikin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capistrano-2.13.4/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:107: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/nporteschaikin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Password: 
** [IP-ADDRESS :: out] Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
** [IP-ADDRESS :: out]
** [IP-ADDRESS :: out] Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
** [IP-ADDRESS :: out]
** [out :: IP-ADDRESS] (in /var/www/vhosts/[domain.com]/httpdocs/releases/20121021210706)
** [out :: IP-ADDRESS] rake aborted!
** [out :: IP-ADDRESS] no such file to load -- rubygems
** [out :: IP-ADDRESS] /var/www/vhosts/[domain.com]/httpdocs/releases/20121021210706/Rakefile:5:in `require'
** [out :: IP-ADDRESS] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/vhosts/[domain.com]/httpdocs/releases/20121021210706 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on IP-ADDRESS
```

Please help!  I installed RVM, Ruby, Passenger, and Rails on the server.

Comment: Were you adding gems on the server while logged in as the same user as  Capistrano uses? They probably have different `PATH` variables so gems may work as one user but not the other.

Comment: My cap and deploy file both have the "root" username.

Comment: How do I investigate and change that?

Comment: cap production invoke COMMAND="echo $PATH"

and verify it contains what you're expecting.